# Electron transition creating Photons

Tags: photons, phase-transition

If the transition of the electrons result in production of photons, Is photon creation is instantaneous?

If Yes,At what moment rightly the photon gets created?

Else, Will the photon be stationary until it is fully energized?

Comment: Did you read what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission) has to say on spontaneous emission?

Comment: That Wikipedia Article is quite technical for me to understand. If you could gimme the answer in a simple English It would be "Great"

Comment: Actually the situation is fairly complicated. Initially the electron is in an atomic excited state (which is unstable) or something similar. But how did it get there? For instance by a Coulomb interaction (collision with an electron) or absorption of another photon. All this must be taken into account for a proper description. Thus we are led to a scattering process from time $t=-∞$ to $t=+∞$  $e^-$+atom → $e^-$+atom+photon. The outcome is given by the scattering operator for the process. No information about intermediate situations is given.

Comment: Time and Motion are absolutely continuous. Nothing can switch over instantaneously

Comment: In quantum mechanics, it does. The transition of electrons from higher energy level to lower energy level is instant.